# Error when installing Swift Open Source Xcode Toolchain: You cannot install Swift Open Source Xcode Toolchain in this location

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I just downloaded the Swift Open Source Xcode Toolchain as described [here](https://swift.org/download/#apple-platforms).

When following the installation instructions however, the second instruction already fails, which says:

> Run the package installer, which will install an Xcode toolchain into
>   `/Library/Developer/Toolchains/`.
>
> An Xcode toolchain (`.xctoolchain`) includes a copy of the compiler,
>   lldb, and other related tools needed to provide a cohesive development
>   experience for working in a specific version of Swift.

I am getting the following error when running the package installer:

> You cannot install Swift Open Source Xcode Toolchain in this location.
>   The Swift Open Source Xcode Toolchain installer does not allow its
>   software to be installed here.

[image]

**Update:**
Someone suggested earlier that the issue might be that I'm not running El Capitan (which is true). I didn't have the opportunity to update my OS in the meantime, can anyone else having the same issue confirm that this might be the reason?

Comment: try repairing  your disk files permissions

Comment: Maybe this is because you have already an older version of xcode installed?

Comment: unfortunately "repairing your disk files permissions" didn't work for me :(

Comment: Same here. I installed Xcode 7.2 beta and it still gave me this message.

Comment: Hi can you please share me the exact link to download Swift Open Source Xcode toolchain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have the requirements met as described on the Swift download page. The error message you are getting is unfortunate.

Install OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) and it'll work.

Answer (score -1):

It happened with me.. then i upgraded to ElCapitan and it Worked!